# Having error pushing docker container on Bluemix

Tags: docker, push, ibm-cloud

When I tried to push my Java container on Bluemix using the command:

```
docker push registry.ng.bluemix.net/shru19
```

It asked me for username, password and email so I put my Bluemix user id and password but it didn't accept it.
Can you suggest what is it asking?

Comment: are you using the "ic" plugin to the cf cli?

Answer (score 1):

The IBM Container registry uses a login token which will be refreshed when you log in. When you receive a login prompt when performing a docker push, that should be an indication that the token is invalid and needs to be refreshed.

Run `cf ic login` to get the token refreshed and then re-run your `docker push` command.